# How to access the "Basic Box Score Stats" table and create a dataset with the Memphis Grizzlies team statistics?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm learning about web scraping.
I'm using the `BeautifulSoup` library...
I can't find the HTML tag for the table to create my dataset for this game (memphis x san antonio).

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_nba = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202403220SAS.html'

#Parse
page = requests.get(url_nba)
page

html_nba = urlopen(url_nba)
soup_nba = BeautifulSoup(html_nba)
```

I tried pulling the "tr" and "th" tags, but it didn't work

Comment: `I tried pulling the "tr" and "th" tags, but it didn't work` - worked fine for me. Where's the code that you wrote that tried to pull tr and th tags?